# Read the first line of the current file to process it in a command (Emulating %TeX root)

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, filetype-tex

Currently I have the line

`:nnoremap <leader>c :w<CR>:!arara %<CR><CR>`

in my `$MYVIMRC`. If I press `<leader>c`, it will save the current file and run the command `arara` on it. However I would like its behavior to be the following:

1. `Save the current file`
2. `IF the first line has the form "%!TeX root = <something>"`
3. `THEN run the command "arara <something>" instead`
4. `ELSE run "arara <current file>"`

For this it is required that vim reads the first line of the current file to process it in a command. I don't know how or *if* this is possible since I am rather new to vimscript.

The above behavior is rather standard in TeX editors and I would like to emulate it in vim.

In case it is important, I am using neovim rather than plain vim.

Comment: Did you check out following question on tex.stackexchange [“arara: making a rule to compile the main file from a chapter file”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100585/arara-making-a-rule-to-compile-the-main-file-from-a-chapter-file) ?

Comment: @Hotschke Yes, I had, but this is not exactly what I want. First of all, if I have a long compilation sequence (`pdflatex-pdflatex-biber-pdflatex-...`), I would have to copy and maintain it in each sub-file with the {files =[main.tex]} option.

And then I would also like my solution to still work if I switch to other compilation programs like pure pdflatex instead of arara.

Comment: I see. Actually, I do not use arara but latexmk. IMHO this seems to be a design flaw of arara. Why did you choose arara over latexmk or rubber? And do you use vimtex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command assumes that `%!TeX root = <mainfile with path>` is in the first line
(and it does not contain a second `=` in `<mainfile with path>`)

```
nnoremap <leader>c :w<CR>:!arara <C-r>=trim(split(getline(1), '=')[1])<CR><CR><CR>
```

Without extensive testing, following matches the first line against `'\ctexroot'` (`\c` means ignore case) and chooses accordingly the argument for arara:

```
function! Myarara()
    if match(getline(1), '\ctex root') >= 0
        echo system("arara ".trim(split(getline(1), '=')[1]))
    else
        echo system("arara ".@%)
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>c :w<CR>:call Myarara()<CR>
```

I personally would not be satisfied with this for following reasons:

- no use of quickfix list and error parsing (if you are not interested in this, you could use something like [fswatch](https://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/) or [entr](http://entrproject.org/) in the shell which means you are not blocked in vim, no need for a normal mode mapping, a simple `:w` is enough)
- it blocks vim while running (compiling latex documents can take a while)

I would consider using one of [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch), or [asyncrun.vim](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will play around with this a little and maybe consider finally switching to some plugin.

Comment: I was suspecting that you are not in favour of plugins. I am not familar with the job api of neovim to improve the code so that you are not blocked when you compile your latex project. But it should be doable.